# Cascading DropDownList in Angular Formarray : when selecting drop-down will change other drop-down's value in other Rows

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown, angular8, formarray

[image: screenShot of issue :]

**expected behavior** : when i select "project" need to change only that row and able to select module based on that. based on selected module i need to select task. (all this three drops-downs are related).

**current behavior**: when i select "project it change every rows in module, and when i select module it change every task in rows.

tried some solutions from stack overflows but its not working....

Comment: If possible then provide stackblitz demo

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349-6pvgkh

my issue is similar to this

Comment: any solution guys ...?

Comment: The problem is, you are actually modifying source list that why it is getting messed